# Removing specific blocks of lines from a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have this certain file with structure like this

```
>ID1
ID1info-----------
------------------
------------------

>ID2
ID1info-----------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
>ID3
ID1info-----------
------------------
------------------
------------------
....
```

I have another file like this

```
ID1
ID4
..
```

Now what I want to do is remove those IDs from file 1 matching those in file 2. So for eg from file 1, I want to remove

```
>ID1
ID1info-----------
------------------
------------------
```

How can I do this in an efficient way. I have a naive way which will take me days.

I have the file1 with 285,000 IDs and file 2 with 47,000 ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[">"$0]}/^>/{p=!($0 in a)}p' file2 file1
```

Comment: The ID part is not exactly ID(literal). It is a string but can be anything?

Comment: Yes, it can be anything. If it's `string` in file2 and `>string` in file1, you just need to drop the `ID` in the regex.

Comment: Actually, I have another issue as well. Could you please help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603019/removing-duplicate-blocks-of-lines-from-a-file. Your suggestions are really helping me and saving me days of work (Y).