# Removing duplicate blocks of lines from a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a certain file structure like this

```
>ID1
data about ID1....
................
................

>ID2
data about ID2....
................
................
................
................
>ID3
data about ID3....
................
................
...............

>ID1
data about ID1....
................
>ID5
data about ID5....
................
................
```

I want to remove these duplicate blocks of IDs. For eg in the above case it is ID1. It should be noted that only the ID part is same, the data after that could be different. However, I want to keep the first one and remove all the other ones. How can I do this in shell scripting manner?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use Perl or Python?

Comment: @Scooter. Yes it is possible. But how to do that in Python or Perl. I want an efficient way to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In awk

```
awk '/^>/{p=!($0 in a);a[$0]}p' file1
```

Comment: You are a savior (Y). You have no idea how much of my time you have saved. You are an expert in awk. Wish I could do the same. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used this in order to remove duplicate blocks of warnings for a multi-module Maven project from the output of Maven Duplicate Finder Plugin like this: `mvn duplicate-finder:check 2>&1 | grep '\[WARNING\]' | awk '/Found duplicate/{p=!($0 in a);a[$0]}p'`